# How to show full text from field in database where there are some slashes

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel-5.4

I have some records like this. Let say

```
--------------------
 ID | Invoice_No
----+---------------
 1  | 123/BDI-03/18  
 2  | 321/TK3-01/18
----+---------------
```

I want to get the data using Laravel eloquent and only show the `invoice_no`. But it only show the first three digits. It will not show the rest of the data after slash.

Is there anyone know why and how to show full text of `invoices_no`?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, that will make easier for us to help you.

Comment: Please describe your laravel eloquent code.